# Scroll v/s tab-based layout within an app - Is there evidence that tabs work better?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, user-research, usability-testing, usability-study

So, I am working on a climate change app wherein people can view and compare their carbon footprint. We need to showcase recommended actions to reduce that footprint and then those actions turn into goals. These goals also need to be tracked. In user research, it has come to light that some people don't scroll while some do. Based on this, I thought of having a tab based layout like below. [image: Mockup]

Is there any evidence that shows tabs don't work. I am not completely against scrolling. Just wanted to ensure that users are able to browse through the content seamlessly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be enough [evidence](https://uxmyths.com/post/654047943/myth-people-dont-scroll) to show that people scroll. I would therefore not limit myself to only using tabs.

Maybe the connection between content above and below the fold is not strong enough which leads to people not scrolling. You could also introduce CTA ("Reduce Carbon Footprint") to automatically scroll the user to the relevant section in your app.